# convert serial port sounds into microphone input

Tags: java, windows, audio, serial-port, communication

Assume that there are two computers, two headsets with microphone.One PC (A) is having a user and one PC (B) does not have a user, but it is having a software which makes automated calls. Now B making a call to A and Playing  something like "Please say 'DONE' if you already in your seat." Then A response for it by saying "DONE". Now here what I want to do is, When that person response it comes to the speaker as incoming audio.I want to make that same incoming voice as the input for microphone. because my voice recognition software only convert microphone inputs to words.

If someone understand my problem please reply/advice me. Upto now I used a windows function in my sound card (Listen to the device), but as the solution its not worthy since that voice is not clear and voice volume not enough for voice recognition.

Thank you.

Comment: Isnt there anyone to help ?

Comment: Perhaps you should try again to explain your problem? I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to do and what your actual problem is.

Comment: @jarnbjo :- ooopz ok. I am doing a java software which can dial and receive calls. Now its working fine. Now from B to A making an automated call as I mentioned in the question. In simply I want to write every single word that the person in PC A response to the call(text file located in the PC B).Not record.I want to write. To do that I used java voice recognition and its working fine when I directly speak to the microphone. but its not working when I am getting the response from PC B.